# How to create multiple secondary tiles for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to create multiple tiles. I have the ID one secondary tile.

```
public const string appbarTileId = "MySecondaryTile";
```

How can I use that ID and create multiple tiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1 secondary tiles works just like the original tile with the difference that it has an id. The id is set then the secondary tile is created:

```
var secondaryTile = new SecondaryTile(
                    "secondaryTileId",
                    "Text shown on tile",
                    "secondTileArguments",
                    new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/image.jpg", UriKind.Absolute),
                    TileSize.Square150x150);

bool isPinned = await secondaryTile.RequestCreateAsync();
```

**Edit**
For pinning multiple ones inside for loop

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var secondaryTile = new SecondaryTile(
                           i.ToString(),
                           "Text shown on tile",
                           "secondTileArguments",
                           new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/image.png", UriKind.Absolute),
                           TileSize.Square150x150);

                bool isPinned = await secondaryTile.RequestCreateAsync();
            }
```

Comment: OKay..fine.. I am using appbar to pin and unpin the secondary tiles. Should I use that ID in loop to create multiple secondary tiles??

Comment: OK thank you. Got it ...I've one more issue..please suggest me an solution for this question too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394622/how-to-pin-a-secondary-tiles-for-each-listview-clicked-item-in-windows-phone-8-1